# Implement genarating function for a combinatorial question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I've tried to solve the following question by using generating functions.I know  It's pretty simple to do it with Inclusion–exclusion principle but I insist to solve it with other technique as well.

Q: how many combination to spread 10 balls into 5 boxes when in each box there is at least one ball.

A:
$
(x+x^2+x^3+x^4...)^5 = x^5(1+x+x^2+x^3...)^5 = x^5 \frac{1}{(1-x)^5} = x^5 \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{n+5-1}{5-1}x^n$

I want the coefficient of $x^{10}$ so $n=5$ which is $\binom{9}{4} = 126$

sadly it isn't the same answer like the Inclusion–exclusion principle, i guess my series isn't right but I can't see why.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) that $\binom{9}{4}$ is correct.  Put one ball in each box to begin with, so the question reduces to how many ways are there to put the remaining $5$ balls in $5$ boxes, and stars and bars gives $\binom{9}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

This is small enough to check by hand which of your results (if either) is correct.

$6$: $5$ arrangements

$5$, $2$: $5\cdot4=20$ arrangements

$4$, $3$: $5\cdot4=20$ arrangements

$4$, $2$, $2$: $5\cdot\binom42=30$ arrangements

$3$, $3$, $2$: $5\cdot\binom42=30$ arrangements

$3$, $2$, $2$, $2$: $5\cdot4=20$ arrangements

$2$, $2$, $2$, $2$, $2$: $1$ arrangement

The total is $126$, so the error seems to be in your application of the inclusion–exclusion principle.

Comment: And if the balls are all different from each other ? Is there option to do it with generating functions ?

Comment: @MatResearch: Not that I know of. But that's really a subject for a new question.

Comment: @MatResearch: You can use the approach given [here on p. $354$](https://books.google.de/books?id=TU1ZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA354&lpg=PA354&dq=distinguishable+balls+generating+function&source=bl&ots=mUM5o6CAW1&sig=nhXzk5T4LoGsWxYfl94ZyZvvP3U&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN6ebqgZ_cAhUGL1AKHQg1BcwQ6AEIXTAF#v=onepage&q=distinguishable%20balls%20generating%20function&f=false) (in particular the enumerator given in $(9.21)$, with the $1$ dropped to enforce occupancy) to represent the case of distinguishable balls with generating functions. Essentially this boils down to inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @MatResearch: The details are too much for the comments here; see if you can understand it from the book link above; if not, feel free to ask a new question about it and notify me here so I'm aware of it.

Comment: I didn't work with exponential generating functions yet. I'll read and learn it. Thank you.